# How to bootstrap Spring Data KeyValue?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-keyvalue

[Spring Data KeyValue](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/keyvalue/docs/current/reference/html/) looks great for quickly knocking up a mock microservice. How can I bootstrap it with data?

I tried adding stuff to the `KeyValueAdapter`, but by specifying the bean myself, I've ended up with `Repository`s that have been wired with a *different* `KeyValueAdapter`, and so don't have the data available.

```
@Configuration
@EnableMapRepositories
public class PersistenceConfig
{
    @Bean
    public KeyValueAdapter keyValueAdapter() {
        KeyValueAdapter adapter = new MapKeyValueAdapter(ConcurrentHashMap.class);
        Account testAccount = new Account();
        testAccount.id = "dj-asc-test";
        testAccount.givenName = "Gertrude";
        adapter.put(testAccount.id, testAccount, "accounts");
        Account read = (Account) adapter.get("dj-asc-test", "accounts");
        Assert.notNull(read);
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you'd rather use a repository as the adapter is basically in place to plug other `Map` implementations. Assume you have a `PersonRepository` like this:

```
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> { … }
```

Then this should work:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMapRepositories
class Application {

  @Autowired PersonRepository repository;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    repository.save(new Person(…));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I think I'd misunderstood the role of the adapter.